# prove subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the subset $T$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as follows:
$T := \left\{(x, y) : x, y \in \mathbb{R} : y = 3x \right\}$.

Prove that T is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt: 
So I let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ be in $T$.Then

$$y_1 = 3x_1\mbox{ and } y_2 = 3x_2.$$
Thus $(y_1+y_2) = 3x_1 +3x_2 = 3(x_1 + x_2)$. Which is clearly in $T$. So addition holds. Let $c$ be a scalar, then

$$\begin{align*}
cy &= c\times3x\\
   &= 3cx\\
   &= 3(cx)\\
   &= 3x'.
\end{align*}$$
Thus multiplication holds.

I'm just having trouble with how to show the set is non-empty and understanding what that means.
 What I tried was let $(x, y) = (0, 0)$. Then $(0) = 3\times0 = 0$.

Comment: Is there any vector $(x,y)$ such that $y=3x$?  Of course, $(0,0)$ has that property exactly because $0=3(0)$.  (Note that if you wanted you could show that some other vector is in the set -- for instance $(9,27)$ is in the set because $27=3(9)$.) Then you're done.  Good job!

Comment: Every line passing through origin is sub space of R^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bye_World answered your question in the comments. I just want to elaborate on the comment of user354069.

Let $T$ be a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $T$ is generated by one non-zero vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$, say $v=(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Thus the subspace $T$ is $T=\left\{\lambda \cdot (a,b) \mid \lambda\in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$ Hence $y=\lambda b, x=\lambda a$ and thus $\lambda=\frac{x}{a}$ and $y= \frac{x}{a}b=\frac{b}{a}x$ (if $a\neq 0$). So in fact the space $T$ is determined by the formula $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ which is just a line passing trough the origin $(0,0)$. If $a=0$, $T$ is just the vertical line passing through the origin. Hence all one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are lines passing through the origin.

If you don't know the concept of dimension or the vector space generated by some vectors yet, just wait till you do and this will make sense.